# non-smooth convex c++ solver

Tags: linear-solver, c++, software, convex-optimization

I happened to know that there are advanced established techniques for non-smooth convex optimization in research. For example, these two papers:

- Nesterov, "[Smooth minimization of non-smooth functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10107-004-0552-5)" (2004)
- Neumaier, "[OSGA: A fast subgradient algorithm with optimal complexity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1125)" (2014)

But I want to know is there any solver (better with c++ compatibility) that has already built in algorithms based on those methods? thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- [Masoud Ahookhosh](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/masoud.ahookhosh/) has posted a MATLAB implementation of OSGA.
- [Arnold Neumaier has posted a list of non-smooth optimization solvers](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/software_l.html#nonsm) on his web site. The list is a little dated, but useful.
- [Napsu Karmitsa has also posted a list of non-smooth optimization solvers](http://napsu.karmitsa.fi/nsosoftware/). She's recently written a book on non-smooth optimization, and her list of software is more up-to-date. From her list, you might check out [SolvOpt](http://www.kfunigraz.ac.at/imawww/kuntsevich/solvopt/), [GANSO](http://guerin.ballarat.edu.au/ard/itms/CIAO/ganso/), and [OBOE](https://projects.coin-or.org/OBOE); all of these packages are either C- or C++-based. Provided the theory underpinning these methods is amenable to your problem structure, you might find these solvers useful.