# state of art non smooth convex optimization

Tags: convex-optimization

Basically, I am trying to implement non-smooth convex optimization in c++. I am wondering what is the state of art condition of non-smooth convex optimization. For example, what's the best method currently in practice? What is the best solver available? And what is the most recent theoretical progress/ or the most recent review of this topic? Thank you :D

Comment: maybe this: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/16265/14305

Comment: You've already asked this question 4 months ago. And I already answered it.